# awk not working in extracting fields from csv file

Tags: awk, csv, cut

This is probably a silly question but I'm a beginner. Currently having trouble extracting fields from a csv file. Ideally, I want to print it out with li tags with the third column printing in parenthesis. The closest I've gotten is using

```
awk -F'\t' '{print "\"<li>$2($3)</li>\""}' OFS='","' datafile.csv
```

which only results in `"<li>$2($3)</li>"` repeatedly without extracting the data.

Using `awk -F'\t' '{print "\<li>$2,($3)</li>\"}' OFS='","' datafile.csv` only results in a non-terminating string error.

If I use:

```
awk '{print $1","$2","$4}' datafile.csv
```

it prints nearly everything with commas instead of spaces

If I use:

```
awk '{print $2","$3"}' datafile.csv
```

I get:

```
awk: non-terminated string ,}... at source line 1
 context is
    {print >>>  $2","$3"}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. I've also tried using `cut` with no success.

Comment: Regarding `awk: non-terminated string ,}... at source line 1` - note the lone, mismatched `"` at the end of your code `print $2","$3"` which the error message is pointing you to look at - `context is
    {print >>>  $2","$3"}`.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output (no links or images, just plain text) so we can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to print `<li>$2($3)</li>`, where `$2` and `$3` are the 2nd and 3rd tab-delimited field form your TSV file.

You can do that in many different ways, but the two most obvious ones would be either

```c
print "<li>" $2 "(" $3 ")</li>"
```

or

```c
printf "<li>%s(%s)</li>\n", $2, $3
```

Note that neither of the two variations includes quoting `$2` or `$3`, as doing so would output the literal strings `$2` and `$3` and not what they refer to. This is the issue in your first piece of `awk` code.  The other ones suffer from unbalanced quotes.

If you want double quotes around the string, then use either

```c
print "\"<li>" $2 "(" $3 ")</li>\""
```

or

```c
printf "\"<li>%s(%s)</li>\"\n", $2, $3
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, awk does not substitute the `$i` construct inside of a double-quoted string.

```bash
echo foo bar baz | awk '{print "$1:$2"}'
```

```
$1:$2
```

awk does string concatenation by simply placing the strings side-by-side.

```bash
echo foo bar baz | awk '{print $1 ":" $2}'
```

```
foo:bar
```

I see you setting `OFS` but not taking advantage of it: when printing, a comma-separated list of strings will be joined using `OFS`

```bash
echo foo bar baz | awk -v OFS=":" '{print $1, $2}'
```

```
foo:bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be with the `\"` you are using.

1. Once you start a quoted string with`"` it goes to the next (unquoted) `"`. A `\"` inserted inside the quoted string will not terminate that qouted string but will be inserted "as is", i. e.: a double quote character.
2. Inside a quoted string the `$n` values are not expanded.

```c
$ echo "one two three" | awk '{print "$2,$3"}'
$2,$3

$ echo "one two three" | awk '{print "\"$2,$3\""}'
"$2,$3"

$ echo "one two three" | awk '{print "\"",$2,$3,"\""}'   # concatenated quotes
" two three "

$ echo "one two three" | awk '{print "\"" $2 $3 "\""}'   # only one string
"twothree"

$ echo "one two three" | awk '{print "\""$2,$3"\""}'     # two strings
"two three"

$ echo "one two three" | awk '{print "\""$2"\"","\""$3"\""}'  # Using OFS
"two" "three"

$ echo "one two three" | awk -vOFS="," '{print "\""$2"\"","\""$3"\""}' # Changing OFS
"two","three"
```

Those are some possible uses of the `\"` string inside awk.

So, you probably want this:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print "\"<li>" $2 "(" $3 ")</li>\""}' OFS='","' datafile.csv
```